# How to horizontally align Divs generated from rails loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, html, alignment

I am building an online store using Ruby on Rails 3.2 that includes a 'do' loop to pull product details from the DB and wrap the results in a Div. problem is when multiple products are populated the Div wrapping each product info are not horizontally aligned. I currently have the Div set up to float-left this positions them horizontally next to each other but they are not lined up properly (the each div to the right is positioned a little lower than the one that precedes it.

I've included the html and CSS code below. any assistance on this would be much appreciated

HTML Code

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>  

<div class="Primary span 3">
<p id="offer-title"> <%= product.title %> </p>

<%= image_tag(product.image_url, :alt =>product.title, :width =>90, :height=>180)%>
        <hr />
        <div id="promo-header">
         <dl id="tier">
            <dt >Tier</dt>
            <dd class="tier-details tier1-style">1</dd>
            <dd class="tier-details tier2-style">2</dd>
            <dd class="tier-details tier3-style">3</dd>
          </dl>
          <dl id="save">
            <dt >Save</dt>
            <dd class="tier-details tier1-style">$0.50</dd>
           <dd class="tier-details tier2-style">$1.00</dd>
           <dd class="tier-details tier3-style">$1.50</dd>
          </dl>
         <dl id="units">
            <dt >Units</dt>
            <dd class="tier-details tier1-style">1000</dd>
            <dd class="tier-details tier2-style">3000</dd>
            <dd class="tier-details tier3-style">5000</dd>
          </dl>

        </div>
```

CSS Code

```
.Primary {
padding-right: 10px;
float:left;
position:relative; left:185px; 
margin-right: 20px;
width: 265px;
display: block;
height: 320px;
background: white;
border: 1px solid;
```

}

I have been struggling with this for 3 days now and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: A few things - you are missing a closing `div` tag for the wrapper element (`Primary span 3`), and I don't think `3` is a valid css class. Did you mean `span-3` or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a simple mistake text was overflowing from a paragraph outside the div and pushing the boxes down. once i corrected that they all lined up perfectly.